# quantum self-consistent ab initio lattice dynamics QSCAILD

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I approached the quantum self-consistent ab initio lattice dynamics (QSCAILD) method by referring to the article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12867. I have created a latex text   in which I outline the method as I understand it and ask questions in the less clear points. I would like to be able to understand, even in an intuitive way, the fundamental principles on which the method is based. I hope that among you there is someone who knows this method and can help me to clarify.

I have added my method below:

> The QSCAILD package is a python library that computes the effective interatomic force constants at second and third order in a crystal including anharmonic effects. The approach is based on quantum statistics and on a self-consistent procedure based on a harmonic model. \newline
> We take a system consisting of $ N $ ions (atoms with their core electrons) and describe them through a harmonic Hamiltonian $ H_h $:
> \begin{equation}
>   H_h=\sum_{R,\sigma}\frac{P_{R,\sigma}^2}{2M_{\sigma}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{R,\sigma}\sum_{R',\sigma'}U_R\sigma\Phi^{\sigma \sigma'}(R+b_{\sigma}-R'-b_{\sigma'})U_{R',\sigma'}
> \end{equation}
> the subscript $ \sigma $ indicates the atoms of the base, R indicates the cells of the Bravais lattice, $ b_{\sigma} $ the atomic positions relative to the Bravais lattice, $ U_{R, \sigma} $ the displacements of the atoms , $ P_{R, \sigma} $ the momentum of the atoms, $ M_{\sigma} $ the atomic masses and $ \Phi ^ {\sigma \sigma '} $ the second order interatomic force constants.
>
> We define the probability $ \rho_ {H_h} (u) $ to find the system considered in the configuration in which each ion $ i $ is shifted by $ u_ {i \alpha} $ from its equilibrium position along the Cartesian direction $ \alpha $.
>
> This probability (Gaussian distribution) is proportional to:
> \begin{equation}
>   \rho_{H_h}(u) \propto e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^T\Sigma^{-1}u} 
> \end{equation}
>
> where $ \Sigma (i \alpha, j \beta) $ is the quantum covariance (what is that?) for atoms $ i, j $ in the Cartesian directions $ \alpha, \beta $:
> \begin{equation}
>   \Sigma(i\alpha,j\beta)=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2M_iM_j}}\sum_m\omega_m^{-1}(1+n_B(\omega_m;T))\varepsilon_{mi\alpha}\varepsilon_{mj\beta}^*
> \end{equation}
> $ M_i $ is the atomic mass of the i-th atom, $ \omega_m $ is the phonon frequency of the $ m $ mode, $ \varepsilon_m $ is the corresponding eigenvector (called polarization vector and describes the direction in which the ions move) and $ n_B $ is the Planck distribution at temperature T:
> \begin{equation}
>   n_B=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\hbar \omega_m}{kT}}-1}
> \end{equation}
> is a function that tells me the average number of phonons as a function of the temperature $ T $, the frequency $ \omega_m $, the constants $ \hbar $ and $ k $ which are the reduced Planck constant and the Boltzmann constant respectively.
> The Planck distribution is a special case of the Bose-Einstein distribution, i.e. the one in which $ \mu $ = 0 (zero chemical potential).
>
> In fact, the Bose-Einstein distribution has the form:
> \begin{equation}
>   n_B=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{kT}}-1}
> \end{equation}
> Let's see the two main steps in which we can divide the method: \newline
> 1)The $\Sigma$ matrix is calculated from the frequencies of the phonons and the eigenvectors (which frequencies and which initial eigenvectors do I choose at the first cycle to start the procedure?) and is used to generate a random set of atomic shifts $\{u_{i\alpha}^{(n)}\}$ with the subscript $i$ indicating the atoms and the subscript $\alpha$ indicating the Cartesian direction in the supercell (is the supercell a non-primitive cell?) and the superscript $n$ indicating each random configuration calculated.
>
> (How exactly are $ \{u_{i \alpha}\} $ atomic shift sets generated?)
>
> 2)The forces $ \{f_{i \alpha}^{(n)} \} $ (calculated by DFT) acting on each atom of the supercell, generated by the displacement sets $ \{u_{i \alpha}^{(n)}\} $, are used to fit the interatomic force constants of a potential model, using least squares minimization.
>
> You take the quantity:
> \begin{equation}
>    S=\sum_{k,n}(s_k^{(n)})^2
>  \end{equation}
> where $ s_k ^{(n)} = f_k^{(n)} + \sum_l \Phi_{kl} u_l^{(n)} $.
>
> To implement least squares minimization the condition must be satisfied:
> \begin{equation}
>   \frac{\partial S}{\partial \Phi_{ij}}=0
> \end{equation}
> for each $i,j$
> \begin{equation}
>   \sum_n(f_i^{(n)}-{f_{H_{hi}}^{new}}^{(n)})u_j^{(n)}=0
> \end{equation}
> $f_{H_{hk}^{new}}^{(n)}=-\sum_l\Phi_{kl}u_l^{(n)}$
> is the harmonic force.
>
> Within the limit of an infinite number of configurations we have for all i, j:
> \begin{equation}
>   \int_{{R}^{3N}}[(f_i^{(n)}-{f_{H_{hi}^{new}}^{(n)}})]\rho_{H_h}(u)du=0
> \end{equation}
> When self-consistency is reached, equality holds: $ H ^ {new} = H $. (Is $ H $ the real Hamiltonian of the system that I am approximating with a harmonic Hamiltonian through a self-consistent process? Did I understood the philosophy of the method? How do I know $ H $? Since I put $ H ^ {new} = H $ it is obvious that I need to know $ H $ in order to determine when this equality is satisfied!)
>
> If we include the third order force constants in the least squares equation, the self-consistent solution does not change:
> \begin{equation}
>   s_k^{(n)}=f_k^{(n)}+\sum_l\Phi_{kl}u_l^{(n)}+\sum_{lm}\Psi_{klm}u_l^{(n)}u_m^{(n)}
> \end{equation}
> By placing the condition:
> \begin{equation}
>   \frac{\partial S}{\partial \Phi_{ij}}=0 
> \end{equation}
> you get:
> \begin{equation}
>   \sum_n(f_i^{(n)}-{f_{H_{hi}^{new}}^{(n)}})u_j^{(n)}+\sum_{lmn}\Psi_{ilm}u_l^{(n)}u_m^{(n)}u_j^{(n)}=0
> \end{equation}
> In the limit of an infinite number of configurations we have:
> \begin{equation}
>  \int_{{R}^{3N}}(u_l^{(n)}u_m^{(n)}u_j^{(n)})\rho_{H_h}(u)du=0 
> \end{equation}
> By placing instead:
> \begin{equation}
>   \frac{\partial S}{\partial \Psi_{hij}}=0 
> \end{equation}
> you get:
> \begin{equation}
>   \sum_n(f_i^{(n)}+\sum_{lmh}\Psi_{hml}u_l^{(n)}u_m^{(n)})u_i^{(n)}u_j^{(n)}+\sum_{ln}\Phi_{hl}u_l^{(n)}u_i^{(n)}u_j^{(n)}=0
> \end{equation}
> In the limit of an infinite number of configurations we have:
> \begin{equation}
>   \int_{R^{3N}}[(f_i^{(n)}-{f_{H_{hh}^{new}}^{(n)3rd}})u_i^{(n)}u_j^{(n)}]\rho_{H_h}(u)du=0
> \end{equation}
> (If I am approximating my system with a harmonic Hamiltonian ($ H_h $), where do I get the $ \Psi $ matrix of the third order constants with which I can start the minimization procedure above?)
> (Sorry if the questions may seem silly, but I have never approached lattice dynamics before (I have only the main bases). I understood that in the model proposed here the potential in the harmonic hypothesis is developed in the Taylor series in which the oscillations are small around the equilibrium positions of the atoms with respect to their interatomic distances. From this supposition the self-consistent method starts with which we try to describe the anharmonic behavior of the system of interest, finding an always better estimate at each cycle of the force constants per second and third order. From what I understand this approach allows to calculate the anharmonic part of the potential even when this is large, which is not possible with the perturbation theory which requires that the anharmonic part be small, that is a perturbation of the unperturbed system .)
>
> If anyone could, even in a small part, answer my questions I will be very grateful. I would also like to know where are the errors in this scheme that I propose hoping that there are not too many and that there is something meaningful. Thank you!

Comment: Full LaTeX syntax isn't supported here, only a subset of it (essentially the maths parts). You can probably see that your preamble isn't doing much.

Comment: Can you narrow down what is your question?

Comment: I'd like to know if it is correct to say that to model the system I use a harmonic Hamiltonian i.e. an expandable potential in Taylor series.
 Solving the least squares problem I find the force constants.
This is similar to the SSCHA method in which the variational principle is applied: the free energy gradient = 0 is set and minimized with respect to the harmonic Hamiltonian $ H_h $, i.e. with respect to the force constants.
So I find the second and third order force constants that make H_h = H.

Comment: I also wanted to know by which equation I find the displacement vectors $ u_ {i \ alpha} ^ {(n)} $ using the statistical probability $ \rho_{H_h} $.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the incompatible parts of the latex document attempting to preserve the original as much as possible. Is this addressed to CSE community or is it to someone else (The end with parantheses)?

Comment: Actually at first I wanted to put my personal questions in brackets about the parts of the method that were not clear to me, then in the end I used them in a confusing way ... they have no other meaning